# Is there a free and downloadable single-file version of the iPhone XR or iOS 12 guide?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a free and downloadable single-file version of the manual for the iPhone XR or for the iOS 12 that it comes installed with? I mean downloadable (for example as a .pdf) without using Apple's iOS or having logged in to an Apple server from an actual iPhone XR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Books app on macOS or Apple Books app on iOS to download single file user iPhone user guide for iOS 12 for free. Use the following link to obtain the guide:

- [iPhone User Guide for iOS 12.3](https://books.apple.com/book/iphone-user-guide-for-ios-12-3/id1420662672)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to download it using a Windows box? (Question now amended.)

Comment: @ruffle No, the books app is not available for Windows. However, you can transfer the downloaded epub book from a Mac to Windows. Details on how to locate the book are here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259844/279727

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is a bit of a Catch 22, because I've just bought an XR, have no other device running an Apple OS, and would like to read the manual, preferably in hardcopy, before switching on the XR and doing things with it - or at least I'd like to have the manual in front of me on my desk when I do the first few things with the XR.

Comment: @ruffle You can access the Web version here: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/iphone/welcome/ios While it may not be printer friendly, you can read it in a Web browser on your Windows box.

Comment: Thanks. I've now copied and pasted the manual in pieces to make a document of more than 400 pages, which I'm in the process of printing. Apple ship the XR in amazingly beautiful packaging, which must have cost a fortune to design. It's a shame they don't include the manual which contains information about turning on, setting up, connecting to the internet, what the buttons are for, basic gestures, changing the screen appearance, the status icons, and much more besides - very useful for those who haven't used an iPhone before.

Comment: @ruffle The general idea behind Apple products is that they are designed to be easy to use. Thus they include minimal manuals/paperwork. However for those who need it, manuals are available on the Web or in the form of Apple Book.